# how to escape ^ in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

Below are my codes.

`url.py`

```
app_name = 'home'
urlpatterns = [
...
    path(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        views.Certification.as_view(), name='activate'),

]
```

`acc_active_emal.html`

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},
Please click on the link to confirm your registration,
{{ domain }}{% url 'home:activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

`views.py`

```py
    def post(self, request, pk = None):
        ...
        message = render_to_string('registration/acc_active_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': 'mydomain', # current_domain
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode((user.pk).to_bytes(5, 'little')),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email = EmailMessage(
            mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
        )
        email.send()
        return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
```

When user sign up my site, I send `active_email` to confirm registration.

But email send url like below.

mydomain/%5Eactivate/(%3FPFwAAAAA%5B0-9A-Za-z_%5C-%5D+)/(%3FPaxyoyt-906068a2d7255bc3da520c10c5793d22%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,13%7D-%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%7B1,20%7D)/$

Then my site returns

the current path, ^activate/(?PFwAAAAA[0-9A-Za-z_-]+)/(?Paxyoyt-906068a2d7255bc3da520c10c5793d22[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$, didn’t match any of these.

How I escape %5E using {% url %} ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try encoding the part with url_encoding.

```
from django.utils.http import urlencode
```